# How to make the Twitter API returns me over 800 tweets

Tags: api, twitter, timeline, tweets

How to make the Twitter API (home_timeline) returns me over 800 tweets? For example applications like tweetbot how do it to have more updates in the 3000 home timeline? I think that using a cache system but which one?

Comment: RTFM. This is clearly explained in the [documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/timelines)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not get more then 800 tweets in 1 go.

But you can pass parameters like since_id and max_id: 
https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/home_timeline

If you store the oldest tweet id => and in the next api call you pass in that id, then you will get the older ones.
After that you just repeat the cycle.

For example: tweet id 500 of date 20/6/2015 is your oldest entry.
=> max_id: 500
Will return tweets 499, 498, ... which are all older then 20/6/2015

Comment: I do not exactly understand how it works even by reference to the documentation for Twitter

Comment: This explains everything in detail: https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/timelines and over here there is a an example to use max_id https://shkspr.mobi/blog/2010/06/twitter-api-pagination-and-ids/

Comment: Okay I'm on iOS in Objective C and for now I can have 200 tweets but how to use the parameter max_id and since_id?

Comment: My code : NSURL *timelineURL         = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/home_timeline.json"];

    NSDictionary *params       = @{@"count": @"200"};

    // Create a request
    SLRequest *getUserTimeline = [SLRequest requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter
                                                    requestMethod:SLRequestMethodGET
                                                              URL:timelineURL
                                                       parameters:params];

Comment: I use since_id but I was not 800 tweets, any idea?